# Variables passed to ORDER BY?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the following query:

```
$result = "SELECT mgap_ska_id, mgap_ska_id_name, SUM(DISTINCT mgap_growth) as growthtotal, SUM(DISTINCT mgap_recovery) as recovery FROM mgap_orders "
        . "WHERE account_manager_id = '" . $_SESSION['account_manager_id'] . "'  GROUP BY mgap_ska_id ORDER BY '$sort' ";
```

I am trying to define the ORDER BY with a variable that I can pass through the URL as follows:

```
$sort = mysql_real_escape_char($_GET['sort'])
```

How would I escape this properly in the query string? I think I have the quotes done incorrectly.

Thanks!

Comment: don't be lazy, create link like `?sort=id_desc` then convert it to sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order by statements aren't surrounded in single quotes:

```
"... GROUP BY mgap_ska_id ORDER BY $sort ";
```

Having said that, it is really dangerous to simply accept user data and insert it into a query - real escapes or not.

If you *have* to allow user selected sorts, I would suggest giving them options, but forcing your OWN code to generate the clause:

```
switch($userSort)
{
    case 'id':
        $sort=' id asc';
        break;
    case 'dollarValue':
        $sort=' dollarValue desc';
        break;
    default:
        $sort=' dateField desc';
}
```

then use the variable:

```
"... GROUP BY mgap_ska_id ORDER BY $sort ";
```

This way, no matter what the user enters, it won't bork your query.

Comment: so would $userSort come from the URL? as in the different cases (ie, url.php?userSort=id, url.php?userSort=dollarValue, etc)?

Comment: Welcome in the 20k club! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote the variable in the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY '$sort' 
         ^-----^---
```

Adding quotes like that forces the DB to treat whatever's in `$sort` as as STRING, not a field name. This is perfectly valid SQL, as you can sort on any arbitrary expression, but it's not going to sort your records properly.

It should be just

```
ORDER BY $sort
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of 'escaping properly' The only truly correct way to ensure the code is safe is to make sure that the variable you are including is one you specify, e.g:

```
if('growthTotal' == $_GET['sort']) {
    $sort = 'growthTotal';
}
```

Then include $sort in your query however you wish, because the value came from *your* code, and so you can guarantee it's safety.

Comment: How could I specify thus in the URL? W]Im trying to sort my columns with a passed variable through the URL, but I must establish the variable up front for users that visit the page other than from the link. Here is what I have now:    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
   {
    $sort = $_GET['orderBy'];
  } else{
      $sort = 'mgap_ska_id';
  }

Comment: You should not have the variable coming from the url; this is insecure. You must work out what the possible values it can take are, then check for each possible value in the same way as my if statement above. Use else-ifs for additional statements. Then to have a default ('mgap_ska_id' in your case), have an else statement.

Comment: Philip, if the user is clicking on a link to sort he data, how else could I pass the variable?

Comment: As I say in my instructions- you select the variable based on the input the user gives you, but don't take the value of the $_GET['sort'] directly.

Comment: Ok...Im getting there, but want to redo what I have to make it more secure. If the link is internal and the user is on that same page and has to click on the link to set the value; how does the variable get there? I like Fluffeh's solution below, but still dont know how to set $userSort without passing the variable.

Comment: After some further reading I see that I am passing variables names ONLY for the switch to work. Now I understand the difference. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`SORT BY` expectes column name, not value. So you do not use `"` there but only (optional, when needed) backticks ` if you use table name which is also reserved word.

Also, better  would be not to take column name from `GET` at all but substitute it in code, based on order sent from user, because currently I can feed your query which what I want (invalid column name, or column I want, not you)

Comment: How would a user send the order other than appending it via the URL since its coming from a link? I dont have a form to use for post.